# DatePickerView Frame error without changing it

Tags: ios, swiftui

I use some DatePicker in my iOS project and I got this error:

> [UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid size {320, 216} pinned to {320, 216}

I don't know why I have this issue despite the fact I don't change the size of this component. Here is my code:

```
DatePicker("",
           selection: $trip.date,
           in: Date().getDatePickerRange,
           displayedComponents: .date)
      .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
      .labelsHidden()
```

I use Xcode 14 with iOS 16.

How can I fix this issues?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I has to do with datePickerStyle(.wheel) but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Has anyone found the solution?

Comment: I tried my code on an older iOS version (14 and 15) and I don't have this issue. I think it is just a bug from Apple with iOS 16. I reported it to them.