# DatePicker in SwiftUI no longer works (invalid size)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, datepicker, picker

I've got a simple date picker but since Xcode 14 it no longer works.

```
@State private var current_date = Date()

DatePicker("Date", selection: $current_date, displayedComponents: .date)
                            .datePickerStyle(.compact)
```

When I open the picker, I can select a day/month fine, but if I want to change the year, tapping the top-left part of the picker I get an error in Xcode:

```
-[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid size {320, 216} pinned to {320, 216}
```

I get the same error if I try and set the datepickerstyle to .wheel but this time it errors as soon as the screen appears.

Is it me doing something wrong or is this a bug to report to Apple?

Comment: Tried your code and all works well for me, on macos 13 Ventura, using xcode 14.1-beta, target macCatalyst and ios-16, tested on real devices, not Previews.

Comment: I see those layout errors in the console, but the picker is functionally working.

Comment: @vacawama are you able to change the year on the picker? This is where is hangs for me.

Comment: Someone else reported this a week ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732652/datepickerview-frame-error-without-changing-it/73806292#73806292

Comment: I am able to change the year.  It doesn't hang for me in the simulator (iPhone 14 pro max, iPhone SE 3rd gen).  I don't have iOS 16 installed on any hardware yet.

Comment: Have you enabled breakpoints for layout errors?  I'm wondering if you're just stopping in the debugger.

Comment: @vacawama no breakpoints set. If I comment out the picker the page works fine.

Comment: Running on real device I get this in the console: [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid size {320, 216} pinned to {320, 216}

Comment: I see others reporting the issue on the Apple developer forums too. XCode 14.0